# MongoDB PERL giving error- Can't use string as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use

Tags: perl, mongodb

Code-

```
$col1->insert("_id" => '100',
    "results" => {
        "result" => "1",
        "when" => "sunday"  
    }
);
```

the error is-

```
Can't use string ("100") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/MongoDB/Collection.pm line xyz.
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`insert` method in MongoDB::Collection](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MongoDB/lib/MongoDB/Collection.pm#insert_%28%24object,_%24options?%29) wants a hash-ref, not a list. You want to say this:

```
$col1->insert({
    "_id" => '100',
    "results" => {
        "result" => "1",
        "when" => "sunday"  
    }
});
```

Note the `({` and `})`. The `insert` method actually takes hash-ref arguments. So inside `insert`, it will do something like this:

```
my ($self, $obj, $opts) = @_;
if($opts) {
    # Do things like $opts->{multi} ...
}
```

But your original call will put `'_id'` in `$obj` and `'100'` in `$opts` and that's where your error message comes from. Keep in mind that `=>` is just another way of saying `,` so your `insert` call was really:

```
$col1->insert("_id", '100', "results', { ... });
```